# is it possible to pass a derived type to a class subroutine in fortran

Tags: object, inheritance, fortran

system:

```
mac osx catalina (latest)
gfortran 9.2
```

In the following file I am trying to define an abstract base class, with an interface for a method called print.  The subroutine in question takes in two arguments, a the `parent1_abc` and the `parent2_abc`.

In implementing the method for a child class, I need to pass an argument for a derived type for both arguments, not just the `this` method.

I am wondering if I am breaking the rules on that one or if not, how can I do this?  Ultimately I can overcome this by just not defining the method in the base class and only defining it in the bottom most level of the class hierarchy, not that there are that many levels, but there are of course reasons to define the method in the abc.

here is the file:

```
module dt
  implicit none

  type, abstract :: parent1_abc
   contains
     procedure(parent2_abc_print), deferred, pass(this) :: print
  end type parent1_abc

  type, abstract :: parent2_abc
     character(len=256) :: id
  end type parent2_abc

  interface
     subroutine parent2_abc_print(this, obj)
       import
       class(parent1_abc) :: this
       class(parent2_abc) :: obj
     end subroutine parent2_abc_print
  end interface

  type, extends(parent1_abc) :: child1
   contains
     procedure, pass(this) :: print => child1_print
  end type child1


  type, extends(parent2_abc) :: child2
  end type child2

contains

  subroutine child1_print(this, obj)
    class(child1) :: this
    class(child2) :: obj
    print *, obj%id
  end subroutine child1_print

end module dt
```

compile with `gfortran derivedtype.f90 -c`

and get the message:

```
> gfortran derivedtype.f90 -c
derivedtype.f90:23:14:

   23 |      procedure, pass(this) :: print => child1_print
      |              1
Error: Argument mismatch for the overriding procedure 'print' at (1): Type mismatch in argument 'obj' (CLASS(__class_dt_Child2_t)/CLASS(__class_dt_Parent2_abc_t))
derivedtype.f90:21:38:

   21 |   type, extends(parent1_abc) :: child1
      |                                      1
Error: Derived-type 'child1' declared at (1) must be ABSTRACT because 'print' is DEFERRED and not overridden
```